# response.json return problem - undefinied

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, json, json-formatting

I have got problem with response . json() return problem. I have got two methods one is Mocking List, and another is by JSON. Mock method works superb. but return from `response.json()` returned me undefined values.

The records are the same like in list - 4, but for all columns it returned undefined.

Here is my code:

```
private _getMockListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return MockHttpList.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl).then(() => {
            const listData: ISPLists = {
                value:
                [
                    { Tytuł1: 'WP', Link1: 'www.wp.pl', Link_zdjecie1: 'https://d.wpimg.pl/10002867-366860448/392x330.png'},
                    { Tytuł1: 'Onet', Link1: 'www.onet.pl', Link_zdjecie1: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Onet_pl.png'},
                    { Tytuł1: 'Interia', Link1: 'www.interia.pl', Link_zdjecie1: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Onet_pl.png'}
                ]
            };
            return listData;
        }
    ) as Promise<ISPLists>;
}

private async _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get('https://sharepointTenant/sites/SharepointSite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'Wlasciwosci_toolbox\')/Items', SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
        return response.json();
    });
}
```

Please help me. Here is two code errors:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code:

```
private _getListData(): Promise<ISPLists> {  
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl + `/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Display Name of List')/Items`, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1)  
        .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {   
            debugger;  
            return response.json();  
    });  
}
```

Replace `Display Name of List` in code with the Display name of your list.

Comment: Still undefinied: undefined

Comment: At which line are you getting error? Can you please check the error line in console?

Comment: I have got only TypeError: this is undefined in console

Comment: Yes, But at which line number in your code you are getting this error? Can you please add any screenshot an error you are getting?

Comment: I added 2 screenshots. and I getting too this error too: Key hoverTargetStrings.ariaLabelWithPersonInfo does not exist in string map

Comment: If I put all Your code I getting this error: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Answer (score 0):

I did sample test project and shared in github, hope this would help you.

```
this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(`${this.props.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?select=ID,Title,Address`,
    SPHttpClient.configurations.v1) .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {  
      response.json().then((responseJSON: any) => {            
        reactHandler.setState({
          items: responseJSON.value
        });
      });  
    });
```

https://github.com/OS-Lee/ReactSPFx/blob/master/src/webparts/reactSpFx/components/ReactSpFx.tsx